# React call logger action from reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux

Trying to call an action from actions/reducers with no success. I know this is an anti-pattern, but I want to custom log (will have a log view) of what is happening in the app. A view will list these items.

When running this I get the error:

> Reducers may not dispatch actions

If I understand it correctly I should use actors but can't find good examples.
Any suggestions on how make a custom logger that can be triggered from reducers and actions (works fine from Components)

*actions/log.js*

```
import {appError} from './index';
import moment from 'moment'
import {store} from '../containers/app';

// ------- LOG WHATS HAPPENING -------
export const LOG_ADD = 'LOG_ADD';

export function logAdd(item){
    return {
        type: LOG_ADD,
        item: item
    }
}

export function triggerLog(log){
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    dispatch(logAdd(log));
  }
}

export const LOG_ITEM_ERROR = "logerror";
export const LOG_ITEM_NOTIFY = "lognotify";

export class Log {

  constructor(type,title,msg1,msg2) {
    this.date = moment().unix();
    this.type = type;
    this.title = title;
    this.msg1 = msg1;
    this.msg2 = msg2;
  }

  static error(title,msg1,msg2){
    dispatch( triggerLog( new Log(LOG_ITEM_ERROR,title,msg1,msg2) ) );
  }

  static notify(title,msg1,msg2){
    store.dispatch( triggerLog( new Log(LOG_ITEM_NOTIFY,title,msg1,msg2) ) );
  }

}
```

*reducers/version.js*

```
export default function version(state = initialVersion,action){
    switch(action.type){
        case VERSION_RESPONSE:
            if(action.json.UpdateRequired){
              console.log("FORCE UPDATE");
              Log.error('Version','Force update');
              //@TODO make sure app gets updated
              return;
            }

            Log.notify('Version','Check complete');

            return  Object.assign({}, state, {
                isDone: true,
                isFetching: false,
                isValid: true
            })
```

**SOLUTION**

Upgraded to react-native 0.30
Do not use the dispatch in action:

```
export function getVersion() {
    return function (dispatch, getState) {
        dispatch(mycall()); // <-- do not do this
```

Now the code example works.

Comment: redux devtools didn't fit for you?

Comment: to specify more clearly. This is not for development logs but for production. The app will have a view where these logs are displayed.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to dispatch non-primitive actions you need [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)
Redux has also have [nice example](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html) which is using this thunkMiddleware.

If you only want to log state changes you can use [Chrome Redux plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en) on use this simple [redux-logger](https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger) middleware.

Or write your own [custom middleware](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/applyMiddleware.html)

Comment: to specify more clearly. This is not for development logs but for production. The app will have a view where these logs are displayed.

So I need to create a custom middleware and in that have a lot of switch and if states to be able to log?